# Add elements in the middle of a queue in python

Tags: python, dictionary, queue

Currently I have a dictionary of dictionaries that look like this:

```
dict = {
    0: {
        "width": 10, 
        "height": 5
    },
    1: {
        "width": 20, 
        "height": 5
    },
    2: {
        "width": 10, 
        "height": 15
    }
}
```

In this dictionary I am adding more values, so eventually, `dict[3] = {}` would be added (with a for loop).

But in a point, I want to remove, for example `dict[1]`, so i would pop it out from `dict`. I want that the next value I add to the dictionary goes to position 1 (or index 1), not to position/index 4.

I have been checking on the internet, and I found [Queue class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html). I think that using this class is more efficient than using a dictionary of dictionaries. But it uses FIFO and LIFO methodologies, so it does not do exactly what I am looking for.

Is there any Python class, or a kind of list or dictionary that allows me to add content in the empty position? If not, how could I do this efficiently?

Thank you.

Comment: The indeces/keys don't seem to have much meaning then if you can just put new values at whatever smallest key is available. How do you retrieve the values?

Comment: Just use a [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types). You can randomly insert and delete elements in them.

Comment: Re what @schwobaseggl said - that's true! I've seen one or two cases where this has been useful, but pretty rare ones. What are you trying to achieve? There may be a better way...

Comment: The question remains how you want retrieve data from this data structure? Do you just pop off any or do you need to be able to retrieve by an index/key?

Comment: @schwobaseggl, I will use it for a object detection model.
When an object is detected, I will add it to the dict, and when I stop seeing it, I will delete it. The program will be used for a long period, that's why I don't want to carry a dict of 10000 elements

Comment: How do you know remember the key under which you have stored the detected object?

Comment: To retrieve, I use the index. That is why I want to keep the order. Actually I don't care about the index, just I want the list to be ordered. Because I want that the object 3, is the object 3 forever until it disappears (so if it is in the 3rd position is alright too, that's why I asked about the queues). In the dictionary, there is more data that allows me to check whether is the object I want or not. I put only width and height to simplify. So in order to not access inside the dict all the time, I use the index as key

Comment: You don't need indexes for that; you can use whatever key is convenient and let the built-in dictionary handle reusing memory

Comment: Then filling up deleted keys is not important. They don't use up space anyway. A `dict` with non-contiguous indexes as keys is perfectly fine.

Comment: Just use whatever indexes are convenient; if you want integers, just start at 0 and keep counting up. The `dict` will take care of it

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's really a data structure like this; two options:

- Use a dictionary like you already have and scan it for the next available slot; not theoretically efficient, but probably performant in practice

  ```
  for index in itertools.count(0):
      if index not in data:
          data[i] = value
          break
  ```
- Keep a list of the removed indexes, probably in a `heapq`; theoretically efficient with O(log n) operations, but probably overengineered in practice.

  ```
  if removed_list:
      index = heapq.heappop(removed_list)
  else:
      index = len(data)
  data[index] = value
  ```

---

PS: Per clarification in the comments, the data structure you want is a plain `dict`, with no special handling for the indexes/keys. It will automatically handle reusing the slots.

Comment: If the efficiency is the problem, I would also replace the `dict` by `list` (and "remove" the item by setting given value to `None`)

Comment: Deleting an item from a dict and setting a list item to `None` are both pretty efficient; it'd be a rare situation indeed where this would make a difference.

Comment: Deleting an item from dist and then re-setting it to (different) value takes about 70% longer compared to setting an element of an array to `None` and then to different value. So depending on the use-case, it may be something worth considering

Comment: Right; that could help in an unusually tight scenario

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of the exercise I made a tiny elementary wrapper class around a dict that implement the desireed behavior by keeping track of what next index to use. The class could be improved for sure but demonstrates the logic. That being said, going with a list as suggested by @martineau is probably the best option.

```
class FunnyDict:
    _dict = {}
    _index = [0]
    
    def add(self, obj):
        the_index = self._index.pop()
        self._dict[the_index] = obj
        if not self._index:
            self._index.append(the_index+1)
        
    def pop(self, index):
        self._dict.pop(index)
        self._index.append(index)
        
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self._dict)

        
d = FunnyDict()
d.add({"a": 0})
d.add({"b": 1})
d.add({"c": 2})
d.pop(1)
d.add({"aa": 1})
d.add({"bb": 3})
d.add({"cc": 4})
d.pop(3)
d.pop(2)
d.add({"abc": 2})
d.add({"abc": 3})
print(d)
```

Comment: Right, this reuses indexes in a LIFO order, while my ones do lowest-first; depending on usage scenario, either may be better or worse

Comment: Nice solution. However, you should definitely move definition of `_dict` and `_index` to the constructor. In the current implementation, where these variables are class-variables, rather than instance-variables, all the objects of this class share the same `_dict_ and `_index` variables. Meaning that if you use more than one `FunnyDict` you almost certainly get different results than you expect